# meteor upsert failing when insert works

Tags: mongodb, meteor, upsert

I am having problems making upsert save data as expected or at all.

Attempt 1:

```
Video.upsert({
  user: videoData.user,
}, {
  $push: {
    video: videoData.video,
  }
});
```

Result 1:

> Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of
>   undefined I20170816-12:32:05.868(2)?     at
>   Function.MongoConnection._isCannotChangeIdError
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:641:7)

Attempt 2:

```
Video.upsert({
  user: videoData.user,
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    video: videoData.video,
  }
});
```

Result 2:

> Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of
>   undefined I20170816-12:39:54.709(2)?     at
>   Function.MongoConnection._isCannotChangeIdError
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:641:7)

Attempt 3:

```
Video.upsert({
  user: videoData.user,
}, {
  $set: {
    video: videoData.video,
  }
});
```

Result 3:

> Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of
>   undefined I20170816-12:42:18.915(2)?     at
>   Function.MongoConnection._isCannotChangeIdError
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:641:7)

Attempt 4:

```
Video.update({
  user: videoData.user,
}, {
  $set: {
    video: videoData.video,
  }
}, {
  upsert: true,
});
```

Result 4:

Keeps creating the following document each run (not updating existing) and is missing the `video` field:

`{
    "_id" : "Gs5of657ZqKa4ec3h",
    "user" : "testUser"
}`

Attempt 5:

```
Video.update({
  user: videoData.user,
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    video: videoData.video,
  }
}, {
  upsert: true,
});
```

Result 5:

> Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of
>   undefined I20170816-13:06:13.250(2)?     at
>   Function.MongoConnection._isCannotChangeIdError
>   (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:641:7)

Attempt 6:

Trying to just insert the binary.

```
Video.insert({
  user: videoData.user,
  video: videoData.video,
});
```

Result 6:

Adds the following documents each time ran which proves to me that the object passed is OK:

`{
    "_id" : "ceg3dXWXZoHjcy4AT",
    "user" : "testUser",
    "video" : { "$binary" : "a long string goes here", "$type" : "00" }
}`

Any idea for why I am failing all attempts? I interpret the error message as if it's not finding any document to update using the `user` field but should it then not insert one when it's an `upsert`?

What I want is user document that contains an array of video data docs.

Comment: Could you also show this collection indexes?

Comment: Just default, new collection created with `Video = new Mongo.Collection("video");`: ```[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "meteor.video"
    }
]```

Comment: Last time I looked, upsert wasn't supported by Meteor/MiniMongo. The "Add an index" answer from @styx is a good idea though

Comment: @Mikkel `upsert` is just an `update` with `{ upsert: true }` parameter. And I can confirm that it works, I was using it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you should create unique index on your `user` field.

Next, use `upsert` like this:

```
Video.upsert({
  user: videoData.user
}, {
  $set: {
    video: videoData.video
  },
  $setOnInsert: {
    _id: Random.id(),
    user: videoData.user,
    video: videoData.video
  }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this but it gives me as previously: `Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. The `videoData.video` is a `Uint8Array`.

Comment: @jt123 What version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: using METEOR@1.5.1

Comment: And `mongo` version?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12

Comment: No, I meant `mongo` package version. It should be `1.1.20+`

Comment: ah sorry, it is mongo@1.1.19, I made the project just a couple of days ago and I've ran `meteor update`.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually using `mongo@1.1.22`

Comment: Ok, seems like it Meteor mongo driver issue with BSON. The bug has been reported: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7758 and seems like it has been fixed in 1.1.20: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/8815